# Observable Chain Dies and Intellij Lags/Freezes

Tags: java, intellij-idea, rx-java, vert.x

I have this simple Observable being called:

```
Map<Integer, List<Long>> localLookup = new HashMap<>();
return Observable.from(userList)
                 .filter(lookupId -> userLookup.containsKey(lookupId))
                 .map(lookupId -> {
                    int userId = userLookup.get(lookupId);
                    if (localLookup.containsKey(userId)) {
                        localLookup.get(userId).add(Long.valueOf(lookupId));
                    } else {
                        localLookup.put(userId, Arrays.asList(Long.valueOf(lookupId)));
                    }
                    return lookupId;
                }).toList().map(results -> {
                      return localLookup;
                });
```

The userList is a `List<String>` of size 18000. The userLookup is a pre-existing map and I am creating a new mapping based on what's in the userLookup.

For some reason, though, between the tenth and twentieth iteration of the filter/map the execution of the observable stops happening and IntelliJ starts lagging like crazy and doesn't ever really recover until i restart. My memory is set pretty high:

```
-Xms2048m
-Xmx4096m
-XX:ReservedCodeCacheSize=240m
-XX:+UseCompressedOops
```

And my heap indicator didn't explode: [image]

The only other indicator is that I have a super long string printed to the console of the user id list. Any ideas as to why this observable is crapping out?

Comment: `/simple/complex/`, if it was so simple you would be able to reason about why it is failing very simply ...

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`Arrays.asList` returns an immutable list so when you try to add an additional userId you are going to get an `UnsupportedOperationException`. All of the exception handling is likely what is causing the significant slow downs.

Instead of using `Arrays.asList`, create a `new ArrayList` and then add the initial lookupId.